# how to grab content from google plus business page?

Tags: php, google-plus

friends,

how we can grab posts and comments from gplus business page ?
 My page link look like https://plus.google.com/b/xxxxxxxxx/ .

I got the api to get details from an account using the following method.
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/108189587050871927619/activities/public?key=yourAPIKey

but i couldnt find any thing for business page.
am using php for developing the code.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

A page is a "user" like any other - grab the ID displayed in the URL when you're browsing the page's posts, and look up the public posts for that id.

Comment: thank you for the reply, when i try to get the page details using [link]https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/mypage id?key=key [/link] value , am getting the basic page details only. Is any option to get the posts and comments too..

Comment: You need to use the activities endpoint: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list